# EF CF - How do I build optional:optional relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I want `Foo` to have an optional `Bar` and `Bar` to have an optional `Foo`.

I seemed to manage to get it working but I had an extra column being created on only one of the tables, e.g. it made `InvitationId` and then also `Invitation_Id` in SQL on only one of the tables, even though both entities are setup the same way, but in reverse.

[image: Screenshot showing extra Id column]

So I wanted to make a smaller repro so I could ask the question on SO, but in the process, and although I have just copied the original entities, removed some properties, I now have a different error, which is worryingly non-deterministic.

Ok, code.

```
[Table("Foo")]
public partial class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Referential

    [ForeignKey("Bar")]
    public Guid? BarId { get; set; }

    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

[Table("Bar")]
public partial class Bar
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Referential

    [ForeignKey("Foo")]
    public Guid? FooId { get; set; }

    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

And in `OnModelCreating`

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
        .HasOptional<Bar>(foo => foo.Bar)
        .WithOptionalPrincipal(bar => bar.Foo);
```

The error is:

> The navigation property 'Foo' declared on type 'Product.Data.Entities.Bar' has been configured with conflicting foreign keys.

The original entities still exist in the project and are setup in exactly the same way except they have more properties, but they get created without error, except one has the extraneous FK column.

So there's a number of issues:

- Why did I get the extra `Invitation_Id` column when it already has `InvitationId`?
- Why can I not reproduce it?
- Why does the error now appear? And if I solve that, is it going to help me with my original entities if they don't have the same issue.
- What's the proper way of achieving my objective in my opening sentence above?

Meanwhile, I'm going to begin building `Foo` and `Bar` back into `Invitation` and `Expectation` bit by bit until it goes funny.

**Update**

So I ended up with EXACT copies of the original entities in all but name. These copies caused the FK conflict error above, but the originals do not!!

I then removed the originals and renamed the copies to their original names, changing none of the properties or attributes, and the error went away and I was back to the original issue of the extraneous FK column!

Bonkers.

Luke

Comment: I think your problem is that you have two relationships between the two tables and only one navigation property. In the fluent API you're saying that the `Foo` property on `Bar` is part of one relationship but then you're confilicting this with your data annotations and saying it is part of the other. If that makes sense?

Comment: Btw, I have a theory about the non-deterministic oddness. As soon as I changed the names of the entities, the error went and the extra column issue appeared, so my guess is that the names alter the order in which the EF schema-thingamy-system enumerates and applies its logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, because there is two relationships and it's possible to have a navigation property for each side of the relationship I think EF is having trouble distinguishing which navigation prop is part of which relationship.
I would suggest defining both relationships explicitly in your `OnModelCreating`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasOptional(f => f.Bar)
                          .WithMany()
                          .HasForeignKey(f => f.BarId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().HasOptional(b => b.Foo)
                          .WithMany()
                          .HasForeignKey(b => b.FooId);
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this one is that it has `WithMany`. I'd like `Foo` to have one or zero `Bar` and vice-versa.

Comment: As @octavioccl said, to have a true one-to-one relationship the foreign key would be the primary key on the dependent. This would be impossible to do in the scenario you describe. It would technically have to be a one-many and you would have to enforce the one-one in your business logic.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I'm trying to acheive: In terms of data, `Foo.BarId` can be null or an ID of a row in `Bar`, and `Bar.FooId` can either be null or an ID of a row in `Foo`.

Comment: This actually works perfectly, thanks to the pair of you. But I really don't understand why. `WithMany` is just wrong (even if its right) from an API-usage point of view, its unintuitive.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is in an one to one relationship one end must be the principal and the another one is the dependent, so you can't specify a FK property in both entities. The second thing is if you are going to use a FK property, EF requires the PK of the dependent entity should be FK too:

```
public class Principal
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public virtual Dependent Dependent{get;set;}
}

public class Dependent
{
   [Key, ForeignKey("Principal")]
   public int PrincipalId{get;set;}

   public virtual Principal Principal{get;set;}
}
```

The third thing is EF lets you configure a one-to-one relationship with optional in both sides using Fluent API, but you can specify the FK, because as I said before, it should be configured as PK too, so EF will handle that FK for you in DB, that's way you have an extra `Invitation_Id` column.

To resolve your issue your model should be this way(remove the FK properties):

```
[Table("Foo")]
public partial class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Referential
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

[Table("Bar")]
public partial class Bar
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Referential
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

And use the same Fluent Api configuration:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
        .HasOptional(foo => foo.Bar)
        .WithOptionalPrincipal(bar => bar.Foo);
```

About why the exception is not happened in your real code, I think the same as @user2697817, you  should be creating two different relationships, but I can fully ensure that because I'm not seeing your real model.

A second option could be the solution that is showed by @user2697817, but in that case you are going to have two different relationships.

Comment: I thought the intention was to create two relationships, hence the foreign key on each entity. I think the OP needs to clarify, we've both give two different solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hate this idea of principal and dependent. I have two entities, `Foo` might have `Bar`, `Bar` might have `Foo`. In terms of data, `Foo` can be null or an ID of a row in `Bar`, and `Bar` can either be null or an ID of a row in `Foo`. Simple? Can EF not do this??

Comment: Well, what you are describing fits well with the solution showed by @user2697817, that is a good way to simulate an one to one relationship and you are going to have the FK properties in both entities (and on the tables too)

Comment: @octavioccl Now I'm further down the road this this project, you're actually right. Though the ticked question is right for the OP, as you suspected what I was trying to do isn't "correct". So thanks, I've now implemented the above.